# Where can the newer Debian/Ubuntu EFI/UEFI firmware certificates be downloaded from?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, uefi

Both [Debian](https://www.debian.org/security/2020-GRUB-UEFI-SecureBoot/#revocations) and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/GRUB2SecureBootBypass#DBX_Update) certificates were added to the `dbx` EFI/UEFI firmware database because of the [BootHole vulnerability](https://eclypsium.com/2020/07/29/theres-a-hole-in-the-boot/), and the two major linux distros are now forced to use different private keys in order to sign software they provide. But there's no information on where the new certificates can be downloaded from. So how to get them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263356/how-to-install-new-boothole-update

Comment: I don't really look for the BootHole fix, since I'm using my on EFI keys. I just need the newer certs. For instance, here: https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/keys/ is a collection of EFI certs but it became outdated now. I just need the certs to add them manually in the EFI/UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you have an EFI binary that's signed with a particular certificate, you can extract the public part of the certificate from it:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "" ] || [ ! -e "$1" ]
then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <binary.efi>"
    exit 64 # EX_USAGE
fi

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TEMPFILE" EXIT

osslsigncode extract-signature -pem "$1" "$TEMPFILE"
openssl pkcs7 -inform pem -print_certs -text -in "$TEMPFILE"
```

If you run this on e.g. Debian's updated `grubx64.efi` as `scriptname /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`, you'll get a certificate with Subject `CN=Debian Secure Boot Signer 2020` and Issuer `CN=Debian Secure Boot CA` in the standard output. You can pipe it into a file, and then validate it against the Debian Secure Boot CA certificate, which you can download at https://dsa.debian.org/secure-boot-ca .

Validation example:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile debian-ca.pem debian-signer.pem
debian-signer.pem: OK
```

Note that Debian had to replace only their signer certificate; their old CA certificate is still valid and can be used to verify the correctness of the new signer certificate. I believe the same will apply to Canonical/Ubuntu, but I don't have their CA certificate URL at hand right now. (If someone knows/finds it, feel free to comment or edit it in!)

Source: Andreas Hunkeler's comment at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=925550

Answer (score 0):

See Mitigating Boothole for overview:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/mitigating-boothole-theres-a-hole-in-the-boot-cve-2020-10713-and-related-vulnerabilities

See GRUB2SecureBootBypass for LiveCD repair commands:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/GRUB2SecureBootBypass

I dare not include commands in second link here as it is beyond my scope,  but think it apt to include links here to assist any likely dealing with boothole on Ubuntu.